# Save multiple lines with different degrees from an image matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In order to infer, how can we get 1D arrays for some degrees that we define of a 2D matrix, like [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DaFYAHHEzNX3djdlpQUzdKZFU/edit?usp=sharing) shows with always have the starting point at the center of the 2D matrix. The  2D matrix will always have equal height with length.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking for here? Do you have an example or something?

Comment: if you can see the image ,all i want is to keep in an array the pixels that are on 0 degrees, in another array the pixels that are on 30 degrees ,on 60 degrees and 90 degrees from a 2D matrix.

Comment: @loannis: well what did you try so far? or are you stuck with how to engage the problem?

Comment: unfortunately I dont have permission to see the image.

Comment: @Ben look in https://www.sendspace.com/file/ky5la7 it will be useful.

Comment: @TheMinion this problem it is easy to implement and keep in arrays the pixels of 0,45,90 degrees.

Comment: @loannis So you mean 30 and 60 degree is difficult for you?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Yes and the symetrical and supplementary of those (120,150,210,240,300,330) but if i get the 30 and 60 i will do the rest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
center = [26,26]; %position of your center
size= 51;  %size of the matrix
matrix=bsxfun(@plus, ([(center(1)-size):1:0, 1:1:(size-center(1))].^2)',[(center(2)-size):1:0, 1:1:(size-center(2))].^2); %my generated matrix to test the solution
angle= [0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330]; %array of angles 
angle=angle*pi/180; % changing angles into rad (from degree)
sine_angle=sin(angle); %computing sine of those angles
cos_angle=cos(angle);  %computing cosine of those angles
cos_max = abs(size-center(2))*cos_angle.^(-1); %computing the maximum distance in left right direction of each angle
sine_max = abs(size-center(1))*sine_angle.^(-1); %computing the max. distance in up/down direction of each angle
sine_cos_max = min(abs(cos_max), abs(sine_max)); %checking which boarder is reached first
angle_array = cell(1,numel(angle));
k=0;
while k<=max(sine_cos_max)
    for m=1:1:numel(angle)
        if k <= sine_cos_max(m)
            helper = angle_array{1,m};
            helper2 = [helper, matrix(center(1)+floor(sine_angle(m)*k),center(2)+floor(cos_angle(m)*k))];
            angle_array(1,m) = {helper2};
        end
    end
    k=k+1;
end
```

You must use floor, because in the used example you would otherwise try to adress an element outside of the matrix for 30, and 60 degree. Alternatively you can use another argument in the if case to check if its still possible.

Comment: can you add the 120, 150, 210, 240, 300, 330 degrees so i can test for all cases

Comment: @loannis i modified my solution, I had to change some parts, so i replaced the whole code. Now you should be able to use any angle and any number of different angles.

Comment: the 26 in the if state are came from position x and y of center ?

Comment: yeah, sorry that should be `center(1), center(2)` respectevily. Changing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the center, say `x_c, y_c` then you loop through all the pixels (current pixel is `x_p, y_p`) and calculate the angle with `angle = atan2(y_p-y_c, x_p-x_c)`. This will give you a precise angle so you will want to round it with something like `floor(angle)`. You can then check if the modulus of your desired sub angle (say 30 deg) is 0 to see if the angle is good. If it is you can do what you want with the data.

```
x_c = picture_center_x;
y_c = picture_center_x;
angleMod = 30;

for x_p = 1:pixels
    for y_p = 1:pixels
        angle = floor(atan2(y_p-y_c, x_p-x_c))*180/pi;
        if (mod(angle, angleMod) == 0)
            %push back pixel data
        end
    end
end
```

Pretty simple algorithm, hope it can work for you.